# showing the content of the table in database a list cannot be undone

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite

I have just started to learn programming and I try to build a simple database for my exercise and I try to show all the content of the table in my database into a list in another layout but I don't know why the content isn't showing up in the list.. please help me ..
here is my apps sample

here is my activity for putting all the content in the list:

```
 package com.DennisTA;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DaftarIstilah extends Activity{
    private DataKamus dbhelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    private ListView listContent = null;

    private Cursor kamusCursor = null;
    CustomCursorAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbhelper = new DataKamus(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.daftaristilah);
        listContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        isDataListView();
}
    private void isDataListView() {
        try {
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        kamusCursor = db.query("kamus", new String[] { "_id", "inggris",
        "arti", "penjelasan" }, "_id>0", null, null, null, null);

        // startManagingCursor( jasaCursor);
        /*
        * Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the
        * list (only the 'inggris,arti,penjelasan' column in this case)
        */
        String[] from = new String[] { "inggris", "arti", "penjelasan" };

        /*
        * and an array of the fields we want to bind those fieiplds to (in
        * this case just the textView 'inggris,arti,penjelasan' from our new row.xml
        * layout above)
        */
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.inggris, R.id.arti, R.id.penjelasan };

        /* Now create a simple cursor adapter.. */
        adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.baris, kamusCursor,
        from, to);

        // listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listContent.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        if (db != null && db.isOpen()) {
        db.close();
                }
            }
        }

    @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
        kamusCursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        }
        protected class CustomCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
            private int layout;
            private LayoutInflater inflater;
            private Context context;
            public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
            super (context, layout, c, from, to);
            this.layout = layout;
            this.context = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            }
            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.d("NewView", "*****xxx");
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.baris, parent, false);
            return v;
            }
            @Override
            public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

            // 1 is the column where you're getting your data from
            String inggris = c.getString(1);
            String penjelasan = c.getString(3);
            String arti = c.getString(2);

            /**
            * Next set the name of the entry.
            */
            TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.inggris);
            TextView des_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.penjelasan);
            TextView id_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.arti);
            des_text.setText(penjelasan);
            id_text.setText(arti);
            if (name_text != null) {
                name_text.setText(inggris);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

here is my baris.xml sample :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
    android:paddingTop="5sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inggris"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arti"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inggris" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/penjelasan"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/arti" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my daftar istilah.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text = "Inggris"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text = "Arti"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text = "Penjelasan"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my class that contain the database:

```
package com.DennisTA;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataKamus extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbkamus";
    public static final String INGGRIS= "inggris";
    public static final String ARTI = "arti";
    public static final String PENJELASAN = "penjelasan";

    //Constructor DataKamus untuk initiate database
    public DataKamus(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    //method createTable untuk membuat table kamus
    public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS kamus");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists kamus (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    "inggris TEXT, arti TEXT, penjelasan TEXT);");
    }

    //method generateData untuk mengisikan data ke kamus.
    public void generateData(SQLiteDatabase db){
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(INGGRIS, "run");
        cv.put(ARTI, "lari");
        cv.put(PENJELASAN, "laufen");

        db.insert("kamus", INGGRIS, cv);
        cv.put(INGGRIS, "walk");
        cv.put(ARTI, "jalan");
        cv.put(PENJELASAN, "gehen");

        db.insert("kamus", INGGRIS, cv);
        cv.put(INGGRIS, "read");
        cv.put(ARTI, "membaca");
        cv.put(PENJELASAN, "lesen");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            createTable(db);
            generateData(db);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Oncreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            createTable(db);
            generateData(db);
        }
}
```

here is my main activity :

```
package com.DennisTA;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        private Cursor kamusCursor = null;
        private EditText txtInggris;
        private EditText txtArti;
        private EditText txtPenjelasan;
        private DataKamus datakamus = null;
        public static final String INGGRIS = "inggris";
        public static final String ARTI = "arti";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    datakamus = new DataKamus(this);
                    db = datakamus.getWritableDatabase();
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    txtInggris = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInggris);
                    txtArti = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtArti);
                    txtPenjelasan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPenjelasan);
    }

        public void getTerjemahan(View view) {
                String bhsindonesia = "";
                String bhsjerman="";
                String englishword = txtInggris.getText().toString();
                kamusCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _ID, INGGRIS, INDONESIA, JERMAN " + "FROM kamus where INGGRIS='" + englishword + "' ORDER BY INGGRIS", null);
                if (kamusCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    for (; !kamusCursor.isAfterLast();
                            kamusCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        bhsindonesia = kamusCursor.getString(2);
                        bhsjerman = kamusCursor.getString(3);
                        }
                        }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Terjemahan Tidak ditemukan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        txtArti.setText(bhsindonesia);
                        txtPenjelasan.setText(bhsjerman);
                        }
        @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
                try {
                    kamusCursor.close();
                    db.close();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: @ user3256145 kamusCursor?

Comment: I meant to crosscheck whether your data is getting retrieved from the db or not....assuming that kamusCursor was arraylist, but i guess its a cursor

Comment: @user3256145 how do I know that my data is getting retrieved?
  I'm just started to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving from database as follows:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Variables.TABLE_ORDER
                + " WHERE " + Variables.TABLE_ORDER_CATEGORY  ;
SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("Food_Id", cursor.getString(0));

                cart_Array_List.add(map);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        database.close();
    }
```

Try extending a BaseAdapter and ovverride the following method:

```
  @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return arraylist.size();
    }
```

Comment: where should I put that?

Comment: put the databse retrieving code in isDataListView() method of your class and comment kamuscusor inside the isDataListView() method. Then change your adapter to BaseAdapter and override the getCount()

Comment: can you rebuild my class source code as whole and re-post as comment so I can clearly know where to put those?